# Presentation of data in a SSRS chart

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

Maybe it's strange because I found nothing in the same kind but.. I'm working on SSRS and I have a chart with many categories (A, B, C, ...) on axis X.
I would like to add, on the same axis, a category which is the sum of categories B,C,D for exemple. Is it possible ? 
If yes, please tell me how.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd calculate the total from MDX query instead of SSRS. Using something like this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Gender] AS 
    [Customer].[Gender].currentmember.PROPERTIES("NAME") 
SELECT 
  { 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Count], 
    [Measures].[Gender] 
  } ON COLUMNS, 
  nonempty({ 
    [Customer].[Gender].allmembers 
  }) ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works DW2012]
```

It shows the `Sales Count` per `Gender` and All (sum of all genders).

[image]

Once you get it in the query you can plot it in a Bar Chart like an additional category.

Share your MDX with us if you get stuck.

**ALTERNATIVE:** From SSRS create an additional series to display it as a Chart Line:

Use this expression to calculate the total:

```
=Sum(Fields!Sales.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Replace date

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi ! 
First, I want to say thank you for your answer. 
I think I will use your alternative solution. The first can't help me because it's not the sum of "allmember" that I want. 
My idea was to sum (for exemple) categories B+C+D together and maybe E+F together too,... And then, to display in a chart the columns of A alone, Sum(B+C+D), Sum(E+F). If a user click on the column, we can display details B column, C column, D column, .... 
That was my first idea but I like your alternative solution, I will try it, so thank you :)

Comment: @MiniMonster, I think that can be achieved in MDX, if you share yours with us, we could try to help you.